# Ember.js execute action when clicking browser back button

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I need to execute an API call when user clicks on the back button in the browser and then redirect to a route based on backend response.
I've read about location API but I can't figure out how to distinguish between url changes due to clicks on link and url changes due to browser back button.
Any suggestion is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution and share it here. I don't know if it's the best solution but it works for me.

I've created an array with the list of routes in the order they can be navigated, suppose it's `['route1', 'route2', 'route3', 'route4']`. In my situation, a route can be skipped but order must be maintained. For example navigation path can be

route1 --> route2 --> route4

but not

route1 --> route4 ---> route3

Going from route4 to route3 can be done only using back action (browser button or in-page button).

In `willTransition` action for each of that route, I compare the index of the target route in the array with the index of the current route. If the first value is lower than the second one, the user is navigating back and then I can execute API call:

```
// environment.js
ENV.APP.routeList = ['route1', 'route2', 'route3', 'route4']

// route
App.Route1 = Ember.Route.extend({
    ...

    actions: {
        willTransition: function(transition) {
            var routeList = ENV.APP.routeList;
            if (routeList.indexOf(transition.targetName) < routeList.indexOf(this.get("routeName"))) {
                console.log("GO BACK");
                this.send("back");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd check out [willTransition](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/routing/preventing-and-retrying-transitions/). Since your question doesn't give us a lot to work with, here's some pseudo code:

**routes/some_route.js**

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    willTransition: function(transition) {
      var route = this;
      backEndAjaxCall().then(function(response) {
        if (response.itsAGoodIdeaToTransition) {
          transition.abort();
          route.transitionTo("some_other_route");
        } else {
          // Bubble the `willTransition` action so that
          // parent routes can decide whether or not to abort.
          return true;
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I was trying something similar, but willTransition is fired every time current route si exited. How can I know if that action is executed because user has clicked browser back button or because he has clicked other links in the page?

Comment: Ah yeah, good question. There doesn't seem to be an ember specific way to ask how the user transitioned to a route, though I did find this: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/3087. Use at your own peril.

Comment: I've just tried to inspect values in `transition` parameter but it seems that there aren't any differences in values between normal `transitionTo` call and back button click. I think I have to maintain a list of page visited and the order in which they should be visited and check against that if user is going forward or backward